# How could I use typeScript in function component for type limit and default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have a function componet like example, I know how to use PropTypes to set type of props and give them default value, but my team is using typescript, so I have to know how to use typescript to get this, I tried to search answer, but I didn't get exactly answer, anyone konw how to do this?

example :

```
const List = ({title,showTitle,buttonText,onClickButton,itemText}) =>
  <div>
    { showTitle &&
      <Typography
        variant="body1"
        color="textSecondary"
        align="left"
      >
        {title}
      </Typography>
    }
    <ListItem button={false}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <IconVideocam />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={itemText} />
      <ListItemIcon>
        <Button
          id={"Button"}
          onClick={onClickButton}
          color="primary"
        >
          { buttonText }
        </Button>
      </ListItemIcon>
    </ListItem>
  </div>

export default List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert the props of stateless React components using the `React.SFC` type like so:

```
// Props.
interface Props {
  buttonText: string  
  itemText: string
  showTitle: boolean
  onClickButton: () => void
  title: string
}

// List.
const List: React.SFC<Props> = props => <div> .. </div>
```